# Dynamic rewrite URL in wordpress htaccess not working?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have url like => *http://example.com/A/B/C*
**Note: A, B and C are dynamic**
I need to rewrite the above url in .htaccess of wordpress to *http://example.com/A/B/somestring/C*

I have researched about this on stackoverflow, but I can't get the perfect solution, so pls don't flag this question as duplicate, I need some nearly match answers for this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please use the Rewrite Rule
RewriteRule ^{A}/{B}/{C} /{A}/{B}/somestring/{C} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^section/([a-zA-Z-]*)/(?!article)([a-zA-Z-]*) /section/$1/article/$2 [R=301,L]